# Listen events on with data binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Listview with the following template:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    Source="{Binding Source}" />
            <ProgressRing Width="50" Height="50" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

At this moment the View Model is:

```
public class RowViewModel
{
    private string url;

    public RowViewModel(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Uri Source
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to listen the image load start and end in order to show or collapse the progress ring. 
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: The [BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage_events(v=vs.110).aspx) has events that determin the download state of the source. Sadly, there won't be a fast and easy xaml only solution. Write a Custom-/UserControl with a source dependency property. When it changes, register for the download events and update the ui according to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think setting the progress-ring to visible is necessary - it can be just visible initially. `Image` has the events `ImageOpened` (fired for successful download) and `ImageFailed` (fired when there were errors).

If you want to be super precise and show a progress circle only for the images that are actually being downloaded at the moment, you would have to handle the downloading in code, not relying on the built-in download-and-cache mechanism.